# How to show that if $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$ then $\mathcal{M} \succsim \mathcal{N}$?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, recursion

The complete problem is as follows :

Let $V = \{ +, \cdot , 0, 1\}$ and let $\mathcal{N} = \{ \mathbb{N} , + , \cdot , 0, 1\}$. Also consider the set of all $V$-sentences which are true in $\mathcal{N}$, that is $T = Th(\mathcal{N})$. 
Let ${\phi}(\mathcal{M})$ denote the $V$-definable subset of a structure $\mathcal{M}$.
Suppose that ${\phi}(x)$ is a $V$-formula and ${\phi}(\mathcal{N})$ is finite.
Show that if $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal {N}$ then $\mathcal{M} \succsim \mathcal{N}$.

There is a hint in this exercise saying that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is term without variables such that $(t_n)^{\mathcal{N}} = n$ and that we can consider the function $n \mapsto (t_n)^{\mathcal{M}}$.

My thoughts was about starting from the fact that $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$. That is true if and only if $Th(\mathcal{M}) = Th(\mathcal{N})$. However I am stuck and I do not seem to understand how to continue.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What does $\phi$ have to do with anything?

Comment: This is how the full problem is stated. I used $\phi$ to prove the first part of this exercise saying that, for every $\mathcal{M} \succsim \mathcal{N}$, ${\phi}(\mathcal{M}) = {\phi}(\mathcal{N})$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A minimal structure that is a model of a complete theory must be a prime model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157770/a-minimal-structure-that-is-a-model-of-a-complete-theory-must-be-a-prime-model)

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate, because your question is a special case of the question linked above. My answer to that question (in particular, the two paragraphs before the break, starting "Let $T$...") also answers this one.

Comment: Thank you @AlexKruckman !